# UIActivityViewController getting load after some time on pressing on button

Tags: ios, xcode, ios7, uiactivityviewcontroller

I am using UIActivityViewController for sharing a text on clicking a Button. But, it is getting loaded after some time i.e. about 2-3 seconds.

I am using the following code :

```
NSArray *objectsToShare = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Sharing text", nil];
UIActivityViewController *controller = [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:objectsToShare applicationActivities:nil];
NSArray *excludedActivities = @[UIActivityTypePostToTencentWeibo];
controller.excludedActivityTypes = excludedActivities;
[self presentViewController:controller animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Can anybody tell me, what wrong I am doing.

Comment: that code looks ok. so what is likely happening: is that you block the main thread and keep it busy so it can't update the screen

Comment: I am not doing any background calls..just I am pressing on button.It takes so much time for the first time. After that it doesn't take so much time

Comment: Any idea to make it fast

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Worked fine on Device but was not working on Simulator